# Attempting to use the mongoose "findOne" build-in method in a generic function

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have a typescript generic function as following:

```
function foo<T>(model:T): Promise<Response>{
  return model.findOne(email)
}
```

to call the function I do the following:

```
const result = await foo<'IUserModel>(User)'>
(* for those who are confused about the ' ', please ignore them *)
```

when I do this, I receive the following error which is:

```
*** Property 'findOne does not exist' on type 'T' ***
```

I read the mongoose documentation about the `Model` object but this did not help me.

Which interface or type or alternative solution is available to get rid of this typescript error?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using a generic function without a constraint (`extends`) in the parameter tells TypeScript that `model` can be anything. So you could use a number, for example, and a number doesn't have the `.findOne()` function:

```
function foo<T>(model: T): Promise<Response> {
  return model.findOne() // error
}

foo(10) // no error
```

Using `extends` tells TypeScript that the `model` must have the `Model` properties, so it will always have the `findOne()` function:

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

function foo<T extends Model>(model: T): Promise<Response> {
  return model.findOne() // no error
}

foo(10) // error, it must be a Model
```

Comment: The Model that you are using for T extending ruiquires 1 to 5 types arguments

Comment: Lucas I think you are forgetting the main concept of generics which is code reusable  .

Answer (score 1):

@Lucas Surdi Franco had opened a way of solution for me.

to resolve my problem I had to extend T with Model

code solution:

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';

function foo<T extends Model<T>>(model: T): Promise<Response> {
  return model.findOne()
```

If there is a nicer solution for this, feel free to comment